# Import LDIF file to external server

Tags: ldap, amazon-ec2, replication, ejabberd

As a follow-up to my [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/101995/replicate-portion-of-an-ldap-directory-to-external-server), which I've resolved part of, what we're trying to do now is take an exported .ldif file of the "Users" container on our OS X Server and import it into a separate OpenLDAP server on an EC2 instance.  This we'll use for LDAP user authentication of other apps without having to open our internal network to LDAP traffic.

The exported .ldif file thinks the DN of the "Users" container is `cn=users,dc=server,dc=domain,dc=com`.  Is it easiest to configure the EC2 OpenLDAP server to think that it's domain is the same so the container is imported to the proper place?  Or should we edit the text of the .ldif file to change the DN to match the external naming?

Hopefully that makes sense... but I'm confused as to the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a find and replace on the LDIF file to change the DN to match the external naming.

Comment: Of course, be sure to backup the LDAP before doing this in case you need to restore.

Comment: A great tool to use for this stuff is Apache Directory Studio.